# How can I update gcc to the latest version in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, upgrade, gcc

I have Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit with gcc 4.4.3 currently installed on it. I want to upgrade it to gcc 4.6.1.

1. How to update using Ubuntu Package Manager:

   ```
   apt-get upgrade/install
   ```
2. As a second option I downloaded the latest gcc snapshot file from:

   > http://gcc.cybermirror.org/snapshots/LATEST-4.7/gcc-4.7-20110709.tar.bz2

How do I configure, compile, and install it?

Comment: Btw, Ubuntu specific questions can also be asked at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) StackExchange site.

Comment: [How to install and use GCC g++ v4.7 and C++11 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can get it by adding this PPA to your repositories:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test

You can add the PPA by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

After it's in the repositories (and after running `apt-get update`) you should be able to either 1) update to the latest version using `apt-get upgrade`, or possibly 2) you'll have it available as a separate package you need to you'll need to `apt-get install`. I'm not sure which is the case with this package.

Further information: [Guide on how to add a PPA to your repositories.](https://launchpad.net/+help/soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html)

Comment: Did not work. After `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` and `sudo apt-get update`, both `sudo apt-get upgrade gcc` and `sudo apt-get upgrade g++-4.7` did nothing. I have a stock 11.10 64bit install.

Answer (score 43):

Add https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test to your repositories by running:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

Then follow the steps on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/23678) to map `gcc` to the version you just installed.

In our case, you want to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6
sudo apt-get install g++-4.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 20
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Comment: +1, this worked for me. The last line needs code formated but it wasn't a big enough edit to allow the change.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get latest anything on LTS with the package manager.  It's supposed to be stable with backported security updates.  I'm not a fan of updating distros, I just reinstall and copy ~/

```
  
./configure
make
make install
```

is the general procedure.  Read the options in the configure script...you have to have a version installed to compile a new one.  make install will probably mangle your current install.

suggestion:  if you want "newest" then use "newest" - that's 11.10 at this point I think.

Comment: Have you mentioned updating Ubunut itself. That's not what I am looking for. I am looking to upgrade gcc installed on my ubuntu.

Comment: not a good idea and it may cause many problems later.